# Do I need the dev kit in order to release for Wii U?

Tags: unity, nintendo, wii

In nintendo's developper [website](https://wiiu-developers.nintendo.com/) I found this quote.

> Q: How much does it cost to develop on Wii U?
>
> It’s free of charge to participate in the program and to submit games
>   to Nintendo for technical certification. There is some cost involved
>   for Wii U development hardware, but we run a program to help
>   developers who are just getting started.

Now is it necessary to get those dev kits? I mean if I have my own personal console. Use Unity libraries (for example there is a ready .dll for using the WiiMote ), am I obliged to get the dev kit? I plan to develop my game using unity if that makes any changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you do need a **Wii U  Kit**. You cannot build, deploy and run your game on a regular **Wii U** console.

As Noctrine pointed out, there's no way Nintendo will let you publish a game that hasn't been tested on a console.

**Wii U dev kit specs**

The Wii U dev kit specs first and foremost support everything the regular retail Wii U console supports, and has the same hardware specs — the Wii U CPU and Wii U GPU are the same, as are the other features. However, dev kits usually have more storage and more memory to aid developers in compiling and creating games. The kit includes:

- Wii U console with added features such as extra ports, connectors,
  etc. The kit includes all the retail Wii U hardware.
- Nintendo-made software tools and libraries that can be freely used by developers.
- Royalty-free third party software and APIs licensed by Nintendo that is free for developers to use.
- Various tools to take in-game screenshots and in-game videos for trailers etc.
- Wii U games are usually written in C++. The Wii U dev kit includes a custom compiler.
- Tech support from Nintendo developers and experts on software, APIs, and the Wii U operating system.

Source: http://wiiudaily.com/wii-u-dev-kit/

Comment: what about when developing for the wii? The wii U is backwards compatible isn't it? so developing using only the Wii Mote and Unity and if in Unity Settings I choose deploy for wii U (or for wii) do I really need it? I understand that I do need it if I am going to test my Wii U games but what about Wii games? (which can be freely tested within unity or in dolphin emulator)

Comment: @JohnDemetriou If you plan to publish a game w/ Nintendo's approval you need the kit. There is no way around it. They will not allow you to deploy a game that has not been built (in the compilation sense) / tested on the platform.

Comment: @Noctrine add that in the answer and I think I'm covered

Answer (score 3):

Nintendo has now opened up for small firms, and even individuals to get access to not only the official SDK, but also developer kits.

You can check it out at [developer.nintendo.com](http://developer.nintendo.com).

Comment: I am aware of that. I already had signed up for the developer license when I asked the question .What I wanted to know is if the DevKit hardware was necessary